# submit button working if id is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery is not working. It is a functions that should update a number from my form. I tried to set a "Hello World" on my external JavaScript, to see if the script is called. That is working, IF I remove the id="sub" in my button type="submit". If the id="sub" is in my button type="submit" the hello world is not functioning, which means that my script below is not working, since I need the id="sub".

Can anybody see why that is happening?

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 bg-success">Content
    <form class="form-inline" id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputNumber"></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput" placeholder="Number">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</button>

        </div>

    </form>
<span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    // Insert function for number
function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
         $(this).val('');
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#sub").click( function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // remove default action(submitting the form) 
       $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){            
         $("#result").html(info);
       });
       clearInput();
    });
    });


// Recieve data from database
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function () {
        $('.latestnumbers').load('response.php')
      }, 3000);
    });
```

Return from database in div:

```
 <!-- Show Numbers In Left Side-->

                <div class="col-lg-1" id="show" style="list-style:none; padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <div class="fixed-width-col border" class="latestnumbers">
                        <?php include('response.php');?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Try removing the e.preventDefault();

Comment: Hello. Is it a fiddle from all my page?. If I remove the e.preventDefault();, I am directed to a new blank page. The number is added when I go back, but there is also a 0 added.

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use `type='submit'` for `<button>`. Try use `<input>` instead of `<button>` or remove `type`. And check again `</label>` and input should be `<input...../>` not `<input ....>`

Comment: Hello Mr.Neo. I tried to add: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</input> , but it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 bg-success">Content
  <form class="form-inline" id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post" onSubmit="return sayHello()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputNumber">
        <Label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput" placeholder="Number">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</button>
          <span id="result"></span>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
function sayHello() {
  alert("Hello World");
  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sub").click(function(e) {
    sayHello();
  });
});
```

Here is the JS Fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/2b0noxjw/6/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is working, but I cannot figure how you integrate the actual function in the js, and not Hello World. That was just a test to see if the script was called.

Comment: @Julie24 try to call the actual function it should work. There is no reason it will not work

Comment: I have just tried to update my question on how my code looks like now. If you have time, I would be really happy if you could give suggestion how the code should look like

Comment: You should close your input </input>. <Label> is not closed as well. Besides I recommend you to move result out of your form.

Comment: Hello. I just edited your suggestions and updated my question. I still think it has something to do with the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</button>
```

Please use this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</button>
```

Might be this will help.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I tried to add your code, but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe its cause...when you removed the default action of the button i.e

```
e.preventDefault();
```

You removed the button action and not the submit.
So you can add an onClick attribute to your submit button like this

```
<button type="submit" id="sub" onClick="somefunctiontodosomestuff()">insert</button>
```

Comment: Hello Shrikanth. I tried to add your code, but still the same :/

Comment: Are you trying to modify the value of the input before it is submitted to the page?

Comment: And can you also add the fiddle of this question...just the code in this question is enough

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your time. I have made a fiddle here from the original code from the question: https://jsfiddle.net/99zag2az/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `type="submit"` when the button is clicked the `submit` event of the button is called. However as you are using `e.preventDefault();` in the click handler it cancels the event.

You need to change the `type` attribute of the button to `button` so that it act as simple button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="sub">Insert</button>
```

After above changes you won't require `e.preventDefault()` thus also remove it.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot. I tried to delete e.preventDefault(); and insert the type="button", but it is still the same :-/

Answer (score 0):

You added `click` method to your button, then this button did not call form submit.

You should call it like this on your click method: ([jQuery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/))

```
    $("#myForm").submit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question with my code right now. How does it look after your opinion?

Comment: Do you want to change action URL and then submit form?

Comment: You used `jQuery post method` to submit fotm with ajax and set result after in success answer. it's different from first question.